# "select from where" statement not working when passing json data from android code to php file

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

The code is working fine when I insert values into the database. The code works when I use

```
select * from tblLogin
```

but when I take the $_POST values from android code and try to run the

```
SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE username='$username' AND   password='$password'
```

statement it does not work fine.

**php**

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("ntu", $db);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

    $a = array(); 
    $index = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    {
        $a[$index] = $row;
        $index++;
    }

    echo json_encode(array("students"=>$a));

    mysql_close($db);
}

?>
```

**android code**

```
 package com.example.digi.studentapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText username,password;
Button login,register;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
//String insert = "http://192.168.1.104/android/insert.php";
String checklogin = "http://192.168.1.104/android/login.php";
TextView result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    checklogin, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                            JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("students");
                            for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject tblLogin = students.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = tblLogin.getString("id");
                                String username = tblLogin.getString("username");
                                String password = tblLogin.getString("password");

                                result.append(id+" "+username+" "+password+"\n");

                            }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }

            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    });


  }


}
```

Comment: where are you passing `username` and `password` in your network call ?

Comment: `echo $username . $password;`. What is the result ?

Comment: 1 - Your query is wide open to SQL injection. 2 - Don't use mysql_* functions, they're deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO instead, and prepared statements.

Comment: Are you get the values of $_POST['username'];
   $_POST['password'] ; confirm that values are getting or not

Comment: echo $username and $password works fine ... it gives correct values from database ... i guess something is wrong with the query

Comment: echo this `"SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"` & see what it gives you. Run the query from phpmyadmin or console & have a check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in php but `username='$username'` seems wrong!
try `username='.$username.'`

Do the same for the variables you want to use in your request.

Comment: Wrong, variables can be passed directly into strings when those strings are enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: This is not the problem. The query is completely fine.

Comment: My bad then :) I used to insert my variable into string this way.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your sql query using the below:

```
// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";

$sql = mysql_query($query);

if (!$sql) 
{
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
```

And Please! stop using mysql_query, it's deprecated and your method makes your application vulnerable

**EDITED**
You can test your results by making a POST request outside the app using something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)